# Quick way to write JavaScript that requires babel and run it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

**I want to write a JavaScript example and run it to see how something works.**

The sample code might require a browser but not always.  I'm open to two solutions, one that works with NodeJS, and one that is used for browser based code.  In browser, I'm using React with *class* and other ES6 syntax including import/export which is not (yet) supported directly by node or node --harmony.

In Python, Java/Groovy, C/C++, C#, others, I could just run a command to compile the file and then run the executable (or just interpret the code), so I'm looking for something similar for JavaScript.

Conceptually, I would like to say:

```
dotranspile --out bundle.js main.js
node bundle.js  (or firefox index.html, which loads bundle.js)
```

The key is that I don't want to have to create a webpack configuration file in every directory.  I thought I found a command like this when searching one day, but can't find it now.

**How do other people run javascript sample programs when babel/transpiling is required?  I would also like to be able to save them for future reference (in some cases).**

Currently, each time I want to write a test I create a directory with a webpack.config file, package.json, and use npm install, and npm run to run the code or start a NodeJS express server to serve index.html.

This seems to be a lot of overhead for a quick test, and it results in dozens of node_module directories with tons of files in them.

Comment: Why not reuse the same testing directory if it's just for sample programs, or copy an existing one so you don't have to recreate?

Comment: If I want to check something fast I go to https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @loganfsmyth, this creates issues when you have a sample that you want to save for future reference.  For example, you write sample1 and save it in directory sample1.  Then 2 months later you want to run it again.  You copy it to the test directory, run it, modify it and need to remember to copy it back to where it was.  Opps I copied it to the wrong directory (sample2) and overwrote it.  I hope sample1 and sample2 are in git/svn.  This is an option if there is not a better solution.

Comment: I haven't used codesandbox.io so thank you @marzelin for that suggestion.

Comment: Why not copy the whole directory, including `node_modules` and the webpack config and such.

Comment: @loganfsmyth,  Sure.  This is an option if there is not a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is not answer that you want, but you can always use jsfiddle with babel + jsx. I think that jsfiddle is very good tool for quick run simple app in babel/jsx or other libs, transpilers etc.

Comment: Using jsfiddle, or codesandbox.io, or codepen.io (or others) can work sometimes but not when multiple files are needed. For example, to answer the question "Is a module initialized/loaded just once when it is imported by several other modules"?  This required multiple files.  The websites mentioned don't allow me to create multiple files.  I do, however, appreciate your answer and I do have a JSFiddle login.

Comment: @PatS ok, so how about use plnkr.co? Plunker provides support for multiple files and also quick setup for packages like babel

Comment: plnkr.co Thanks for the suggestion plnkr.co looks promising.  I tried to run an example that had multiple files and couldn't figure out how to make it run babel, but I'll keep trying.